# TScreen->Forms Shows Unexpected Extra Forms

Tags: delphi, c++builder

I am using C++Builder 10.3 Rio and a VCL windows application. I am using the TScreen->Forms to get information about my programs open forms. This shows a higher FormCount than I expected. My application has two open forms (1)the main program form and (2)a data entry dialog box. When I check the Screen->FormCount it shows 6 forms. When I check the forms name and caption in the for loops below only my 2 forms have a name and caption. The other form names and captions are NULL. I can identify my forms using the dynamic_cast or the form name. What are the other extra forms? How can I identify the other forms?

```cpp
UnicodeString MyName, MyCaption;

for(int j=0; j<Screen->FormCount; j++){
  MyName    = Screen->Forms[j]->Name;
  MyCaption = Screen->Forms[j]->Caption;
  TMyForm *MyLocal = dynamic_cast<TMyForm *>( Screen->Forms[j] );
}

for(int j=0; j<Screen->CustomFormCount; j++){
  MyName    = Screen->CustomForms[j]->Name;
  MyCaption = Screen->CustomForms[j]->Caption;
}
```

Comment: some visual components are handled as windows in winapi with their own Handle ... see [is ther a way an app can display a message without the use of messagebox API?](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/11920/4709)

Comment: @Spektre while that is true, those components would not appear in the `Screen->Forms` list. Only `TForm` and derived objects are stored in that list

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `ClassName` property to find out a little more information.

But that might not reveal anything of use if, for instance, some of the forms are plain `TForm`, or you don't recognise the name. To truly work out what these forms are, set a breakpoint in `TCustomForm.Create` and inspect the call stack each time that breakpoint is triggered.

Comment: When I look at, Screen->CustomForms[j]->ClassName(); it shows "TNoActiveForm".  The property Screen->CustomFormCount includes several of these dummy forms. I will just have to make sure I check the form type and skip these unknown forms.

Comment: You probably ought to think about where these forms come from.

Comment: Most likely, there are components in your project that create their own internal TForm objects for whatever reason they need